# Selective notifications for Apple Watch

Tags: push-notification, apple-watch

Our app has quite a few notification scenarios on the iPhone App which might not make sense for the Watch App. I investigated the Watch documentation to check whether notifications can be Apple Watch specific, but did not find any details.  Is didReceiveRemoteNotification in the Watch code the best way to decide whether to surface a notification on the Watch?

Answer (score 0):

The OS decides where to surface the notification. You have no control over it. Your iOS/Watch app can only respond if it's the lucky recipient.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least for now (iOS 8.3 + Watch OS 1.0).

The phone app and its watch extension is essentially the same app. iOS will decide which notification should be presented on which device. The 3rd party app developers have zero control over this. Users can choose if all notifications from single apps are allowed to be shown on the watch.

The basic logic is: Notifications will be only delivered to the watch when the paired iPhone is locked, the screen is off, and the watch is on the wrist.